# Dataframe in PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, integer

I have a data frame consisting of many columns but I have two columns of interest. 'Age' column and 'Marital Status' column. 'Marital Status' contains some NA values. How do I put a condition that if Age is < 18, 'Marital Status' should be filled with 'Single'?

i tried this but i didn't get desired output

`>>>`for i in df['Age']:

>>> if i < 18:

`>>>`df['Marital Status'].fillna('Single').

I want the Marital Status column  containing NA values corresponding to Age < 18 to be filled with 'Single'

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `np.where` in your coding

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Marital Status' : ['Single', 'Married', np.nan, 'Single', np.nan],
    'Age' : [22, 22, 17, 30, 20]
})

df['Marital Status'] = np.where((df['Marital Status'].isna()) & (df['Age'] <= 18), 'Single', df['Marital Status'])
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
# is the Age < 18?
m1 = df['Age'].lt(18)
# is the Marital status NaN?
m2 = df['Marital Status'].isna()

# if both conditions are met, set 'Marital Status' to 'Single'
df.loc[m1&m2, 'Marital Status'] = 'Single'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set on a slice of the dataframe so something like

```py
df.isna()[df['Marital Status']<18] = 'Single'
```

or

```py
df[df['Marital Status']==None & df['Age']<18] = 'Single'
```